# Compilation problems with XZip and Xunzip in a service

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to add Zip functionality in a windows service using [XZip](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4135/XZip-and-XUnzip-Add-zip-and-or-unzip-to-your-app-w). I get the error of unexpected end of file looking for precompiled header.I have user not using Precompiled Header Option but the error does not go away. I also get macro redifinition warnings for Assert tracecv PUTSHORT and PUTBYTE. The same code worked in a standalone application. I am getting these errors compiling in the service application.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you are getting that error then you must be using a precompiled header. Make sure that you have disabled precompiled headers for the configuration you are building, not for some other configuration.

Comment: I have disabled precompiled  header in all confgurations but i am still getting the error.

Comment: That seems to be unlikely. You are probably mistaken. Can you post the compiler output (including the compiler options that are being used).

Comment: Ok there was a mixup with x86 and x64. I had to set Not using Precompiled headers in the x86 version. Thanks. It compiled.

Comment: Thanks for answer by John